# Deploy to Firebase personalized Hosting using React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, deployment, firebase-hosting

I hope someone could help me to deploy my portfolio on my domain bought from google. I have develop the project in React and to deploy it I'm using Firebase, but I can't connect my portfolio with my personalized domain, because everytime, the deployed code, goes on the default domain. See the screenshots attached to a better understanding.

I also can't setting the personalized hosting during the configuration of firebase by console, bacause the option that I have is always the dafault one. Thanks in advance.

[image]